# system.byte[] error c# when converting from string to byte

Tags: c#

i want to convert string to Byte[] in C# and with the help of previous topics i use this code : 
`string s = "0a";
 System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encode = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
 byte[] b = encode.GetBytes(s);
 Console.WriteLine(b);`

but when i run this code it only prints : " System.byte[]"

Comment: You don't have to create the encoding object. One is provided for you: `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII`

Comment: yes , but either with the thing mentioned the output is just same as b4.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just pointing out how you could shorten your code. That wasn't an attempt at an answer.

Comment: Is 0a a hex string?  It is not clear the format you wish to output the bytes as: hex digits, base10 digits, some other encoding?

Comment: @dana yes , i want to transfer a hes string value to a byte array . for example a "0x18" into an array of bytes .

Comment: Question not clear. Please rectify.

Comment: what do you want to print ? the elements of the byte array ? the original string ? your question is ambiguous

Comment: This answer might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have finally deciphered your question. Are you trying to get the hex digits of your string into an array?

I'm assuming that you want to take 2-digit hex values from a string and convert each lot into bytes. If not, I'm as lost as everyone else. **Please note that I have not included any error checking!**

```
byte[] data = new byte[s.Length/2];
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length/2; ++i)
{
    byte val = byte.Parse(s.Substring(i*2,2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    data[i] = val;
}

foreach(byte bv in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bv.ToString("X"));    
}
```

Comment: Yes ! exactly get what i am saying and this was my answer , thanks ! @john

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this `Console.WriteLine(b)` it will prints the type of `b` which is `System.Byte[]`. 
In order to print the string stored in `byte[] b`, just make use of `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.GetString(byte[] b);`

so in your case, `encode.GetString(b);` will get your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitConverter class Check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

```
 System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encode = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
 byte[] b = encode.GetBytes(s);
 Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already does the trick of converting string to byte, if your query is to print individual byte value, why not use a loop to print the value in byte array:

```
foreach (byte bb in b)
{
   Console.Write(Convert.ToInt32(bb));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because it's returning the type of the object that you are typing. If you want to print the content of the array, try this:

```
Arrays.toString(byteArray)
```

Comment: there is no 'Arrays' in my editor/compiler when i type arrays.

Comment: `Array.ToString()` will also return the type, are you mixing between Microsoft Dynamics AX and .Net Frame work O.o ?